# weird behavior with white-spaces on path

Tags: java

I have this stupid unknown behavior coming up. In my application I need to start a Java process to execute some task's. So on doing below:

```
1a) String[] ls = {"cmd",
                "/C",
                "\"C:\\t e m p\\run time\\jre\\bin\\java.exe\"",
                "-jar",
                "Canon.jar"};
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(ls);
p.redirectErrorStream();
Process pp = p.start();
```

The above works perfectly. But if say full-path to `Canon.jar` contains white-spaces then it doesn't work. Basically I need to add `quotes` around the `Canon.jar` path. i.e.

```
1b) String[] ls = {"cmd","/C",
                "\"C:\\Prac\\t e m p\\run time\\jre\\bin\\java.exe\"","-jar",
                 "\"C:\\Prac\\t e m p\\Canon.jar\""};
```

The above still doesn't work even after including quotes. It says:

> Ending 'C:\Users\Jatin\Documents\Prac\t' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

The biggest problem is, the below also does not work:

```
 1c) String[] ls = {"cmd","/C",
                "\"C:\\Prac\\t e m p\\run time\\jre\\bin\\java.exe\"","-jar",
                 "\"C:\\Prac\\temp\\Canon.jar\""};//contains no white space.
```

It still says same error. How on earth can it say it again when path to `Canon.jar` contains no white spaces. Why does it say problem with `java.exe` path when `1a` worked.

Comment: But Why do you have white spaces in path?, also, in 1c) you still have white space in java.exe path.

Comment: Maybe the `\t` in `\\t` is being escaped as a tab character? Just guessing.

Comment: @Ankit It is for testing - white spaces. In `1c` exactly my point, if it works in `1a` why does it fail in `1c`

Comment: @ajlane In `1a` there is no error.

Comment: try putting the words which have white space in the path with double quotes. for eg. in the command prompt to change the directory to program files.. we need to write cd "Program Files", or else it wouldnt work.. I am not sure if this solves it, but worth a try.

Comment: Double quotes was already added above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need the `cmd` at all?  Consider removing it.

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"C:\\Prac\\t e m p\\run time\\jre\\bin\\java.exe","-jar",
               "C:\\Prac\\t e m p\\Canon.jar"};
```

Comment: It worked. What does `cmd` get here in picture? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: In addition to getting rid of `cmd`, unnecessary quotes around path names have been gotten rid of.  That itself should suffice.  The complete path in the error message should ring a bell.

Comment: java.exe is normally in your **path** environment variable so you should be able to just use java.exe. Likewise, jar files belong in your **classpath**, so you can just use Canon.jar. This gets rid of all the trouble with full pathnames.